# Can't Get _UNICODE Undefined using Character Set Setting in VS 2017 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have legacy code and need to compile code using the ASCII character set. I am using Visual Studio 2017 for C++.

**Edit: At this point I don't expect anyone to be able to reproduce the problem. My installation is 'broken'. However, I'll take any ideas on what I could check to fix it.**

To simplify the situation, I created a simple program, setting the 'Project Properties->General->Character Set' setting to 'Not Set'.  The code still compiles with _UNICODE defined.  How do I get _UNICODE undefined and have the program use the ASCII character set?

The sample program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
#ifdef _UNICODE
    cout << "Unicode is defined.";
#else
    cout << "Unicode is not defined.";
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

More information:
Windows 10
Target Platform: Windows 10 (not changeable)
Visual Studio 2017 (v141)
SDK Version: 10.0.162990

Here's the Command Line Compiler Options:

/permissive- /Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\NotUnicode.pch" /diagnostics:classic

And the preprocessor definitions, as requested:

_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem.  Have a look in `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions` to see what is defined there.

Comment: I've just added the command line compiler options to the post.

Comment: As the command line does not include the define, did you force a recompile of the pre-compiled header(s).?  If not then `#include "stdafx.h"` will be dragging in the old defined symbols.  IIRC changing project options does not force a clean/recompile of the whole project.

Comment: NotUnicode.pch is pretty weird when you use stdafx.h, some odds that you simply use the wrong .pch file

Comment: Is there an old .pch file? This is a new project from scratch.  I tried rebuilding the *.pch file and it didn't change anything.